# Pagination does not working properly with structure

Tags: structure, pagination, freebie, zoo-triggers

I have using structure, but in my listing page pagination does not working properly. pagination links are changed but records are display at it is. means every time same records display.

I have using structure, freebie, zoo triggers and stash.

My script is given below:

```
{embed="_layouts/index"}

{exp:stash:set name="meta"}
{exp:seo_lite use_last_segment="yes"}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set name="content"}
<section id="content">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <span class="logo-icon"></span>
        <span class="left-line"></span>
        <span class="right-line"></span>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <section id="left-side">

                    {embed='home/breadcumb'}

                    {exp:channel:entries channel="pages" dynamic="yes" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
                        <h1>{title}</h1>
                        {page_content}
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                    <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>


                    <section class="all-list">
                    {exp:channel:entries channel="parliamentarian" parse="inward" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" limit="10" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"}
                        <div class="listing {switch='odd|even'} cf">
                            <div class="member-image">
                                {member_image}
                                    <img src="{image:url:small}" />
                                {/member_image}
                            </div>
                            <h2><a href="{page_uri}">{title}</a></h2>
                            <a href="{page_uri}" class="details-arrow">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                        {paginate}
                          {pagination_links}
                              <div class="paging">
                                <span class="page-name">Page({current_page}):</span>
                                  {first_page}
                                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="first">First</a>
                                  {/first_page}

                                  {previous_page}
                                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="prev">Prev</a>
                                  {/previous_page}
                                  {page}
                                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}current{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
                                  {/page}
                                  {next_page}
                                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="next">Next</a>
                                  {/next_page}

                                  {last_page}
                                          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="last">Last</a>
                                  {/last_page}
                              </div>
                          {/pagination_links}
                        {/paginate}
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                    </section>

                </section>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                {embed='pages/right-side'}
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Please help me how to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue; did you solve your issue?

My pagination links/url are changing but the displayed entires is always the same i.e.

url: http://example.com/news/
entries: 1,2,3

url: ...news/p1
entries: 1,2,3

when I'd expect:

url: http://example.com/news/
entries: atricle-1,atricle-2,atricle-3

url: ...news/p1
entries: atricle-4,atricle-5,atricle-6

My very basic code is:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="news"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data"
    orderby="date"
    sort="desc"
    limit="3"
    paginate="bottom"
    dynamic="no"
}
    {title}
    {paginate}
    Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I move the code out of a 'page' defined as a lister in Structure it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Structure 3.3.14.7
ExpressionEngine    2.9.2 Build 20141004

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: ok - found the solution - need to disable 'enable_sql_caching': http://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/7675-pagination-not-working

Comment: Hi user2484138, glad you found a solution and thanks for adding that comment! For future reference... it is best to post your question as a "new question" rather than as an answer. And if you do find the answer please post as an answer (and feel free to answer your own question).

Answer (score 0):

Sweet - found the solution, need to disable 'enable_sql_caching' as per:
http://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/7675-pagination-not-working